# Cannot simulate process death

Tags: android, process

I am trying to simulate "Process Death" in my Android Studio and have done the following steps:

1. Changed Background process limit in emulator

[image]

2. Test app has Application class, MainActivity and Activity2 with just layout. Run the app and open Activity2.
3. Press home button and open more than 5 other apps.
4. Check attatch to debugger and no process exists.

[image]

5. Go to the emulator and open the app from recent app menu.
   [image]

I expected I would see the Activity2 but the app starts thorugh normal process and I was able to the application class started and MainActivity only shown.

Am I missing something to reproduce process death? Quite confused with this.

Thanks in advance with your help.